# Trying to use the same button to play+pause music

Tags: android, adt

I have recently tried to create a button that says "Play", and when this button is pressed, I wanted it to play the music then change the text to "Stop", but it throws an error and quits the app. Here is my code:

```
        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ourMusic.isPlaying()){
                ourMusic.pause();
                mDisplay.setText("Play");
            }else{
                ourMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.killthenoise);
                ourMusic.start();
                mDisplay.setText("Stop");
            }
        }
    });
```

So if you press the button once it should play, press it again it should stop the music. There is no errors in the actual coding.
Here is my logcat: http://pastie.org/7970711

I am new to this stuff, so I don't know too much of whats going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if(ourMusic.isPlaying())` -- On this line, ourMusic might not have even been instantiated. Thus the NPE.

Comment: You have to show more code, or let us know what is on line 49! Also, if you want to stop the music then use ourMusic.stop(); and in the else you don't need to recreate the mediaplayer. Just call ourMusic.start(); (Assuming that ourMusic is initialized before)

Comment: Line 49 is 
           if(ourMusic.isPlaying()){

Comment: the ourMusic is null, put ourMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.killthenoise); in onCreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (ourMusic == null) {
            ourMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.killthenoise);
        }

        if(ourMusic.isPlaying()){
            ourMusic.pause();
            mDisplay.setText("Play");
        }else{
            ourMusic.start();
            mDisplay.setText("Stop");
        }
    }
```

Basically don't:

1. Recreate `ourMusic` everytime there is a click to play
2. Try to use `ourMusic` when it isn't instantiated.

Comment: Stop and Pause are two different things! Could be confusing to the user if you say Stop but are actually pausing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a global variable boolean flag=false;

```
if(flag==false)
        {
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abc);
            mp.start();
            playbutton.setText("Pause");
            flag=true;
        }
        else if(mp.isPlaying()&&flag==true)
        {
            mp.pause();
            playbutton.setText("Play");
            flag=false;
        }
```

This code will work if you want to use the same button as PLAY/PAUSE in your app.
Hope this helps.